# Does zerofree avoid any possible recovery?

Tags: usb, hard-drive, security, data-recovery, ram

Say I unlink a file `myfile` on a USB located at `/dev/sdb1`

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /media
rm /media/myfile
```

and then umount the usb and run `zerofree`:

```
umount /media
zerofree /dev/sdb1
```

**Would this last command allow to avoid any possible recovery my file `myfile`?**

Comment: zerofree only works with ext[234] filesystem - if your USB is formatted with one of these, it should do that. You can make sure with tools like `photorec`.

Answer (score 0):

`zerofree` only works with ext[234] filesystem - if your USB is formatted with one of these, it should do that.

You can make sure with tools like `photorec`

Answer (score 0):

```
 shred -zun1 /media/myfile
```

See `man shred` for the details. On modern hard disks and SSD using an overwrite count greater than 1 is useles (the default is 3 for historical reasons). If the USB drive in question is a solid-state drive (SSD or flash drive) you may also want to `fstrim /media`; try to not overuse this command.